# Variable filtered in angular controller doesn't updates when input changes

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my component:

```
const template = require('./cart.html');
import GamesService, { Game } from '../../games.service';

export class CartComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public controller = CartController;
    public template = template;
}

export class CartController implements ng.IComponentController {
    public static $inject = ['GamesService', 'filterFilter'];

    public games: Game[];

    constructor(public gamesService: GamesService, filterFilter: ng.IFilterFilter) {
    this.games = filterFilter(gamesService.getAll(), { inCart: true });
    }

    public addToCart(game: Game) {
        this.gamesService.addToCart(game);
    }

    public removeFromCart(game: Game) {
        this.gamesService.removeFromCart(game);
    }
}
```

And this in service:

```
export default class GamesService {
    private games: Game[] = GAMES;

    public getAll(): Game[] {
        return this.games;
    }

    public addToCart(game: Game) {
        game.inCart = true;
    }

    public removeFromCart(game: Game) {
        game.inCart = false;
    }
}
```

When I add item to the cart the list is not updated. If I don't use filterFilter in controller and use it in template as "| filter:{inCart:true}", then the list updates well on each change.
Can you please explain me what is wrong with controller or service?

Comment: Well, just read your code: `this.games` is initialized once, and only once, when the controller is first constructed. Why should the content of the array change later, if you don't filter again and reinitilize the array?